# q kdb+ finding index of match elements using a list

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Say I have a list

```
b:1 1 2 3 4
```

and I want to find the location of the element in list b using another list

```
a:1 2
```

When I type in `b in\ a`, I got

```
11000b
00000b
```

where it should be

```
11000b
00100b
```

What is going on and how to get the desired answer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use each-right `/:`

```
q)b in/:a
11000b
00100b
```

With `b in\a` the first output is getting passed back in as `b`. Effectively:

```
q)1 1 2 3 4 in 1
11000b
q)11000b in 2
00000b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use each-both `'`:

```
q)in[b]'[a]
11000b
00100b
```